# Convolution 2 dirac delta with matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

So I want to do the following convolution `(dirac(t+1)+2*dirac(t-1))*dirac(t-3)`, but I get a weird value. Normally I would think every thing is shifted with 3 units to the right but the `2*dirac(t-1)` stays at t=2 instead of the expected t=4. Why is this?

```
%Chapter 3_a
clear all 
close all
clc

%% excercise 3

t = -5:0.1:5;
x_1 = dirac(t+1);
idt = x_1 == Inf; % find Inf
x_1(idt) = 1;     % set Inf to finite value


x_2 = 2*dirac(t-1);
idt = x_2 == Inf; % find Inf
x_2(idt) = 1;     % set Inf to finite value

figure
x = x_1 + x_2;
stem(t,x)
hold on

figure
y = dirac(t-3);
idt = y == Inf; % find Inf
y(idt) = 1;     % set Inf to finite value
stem(t,y)

figure
w = conv(x,y)
t_2 = linspace(-5,5,length(w));;
stem(t_2,w)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your second to last line,

> `t_2 = linspace(-5,5,length(w));`

To understand how to fix this line, it should be first noted that `conv` knows nothing about the time axes. When you compute `w = conv(x,y)`, it is only assumed that

1. The **time between samples is constant** for both inputs `x` and `y`.
2. The finite sequences `x` and `y` are thought of as being **implicitly extended with zeros** to the left and to the right.

The result `w` has a length equal to the `length(x)+length(y)-1`. This is because `conv` computes the output with the **minimum length** that ensures that all values outside that length would necessarily be zero (because of assumption 2). For example,

```
>> x = [1 1 1];
y = [1 1 1 1];
w = conv(x, y)

w =
     1     2     3     3     2     1
```

As is seen, there is no reference to the time axes in the inputs or in the output. It does not matter, for example, if `x` starts at *t*=`0` or at *t*=`8`. So you need to **keep track of the time axes separately**. Specifically, if (the specified portions of) `x` and `y` start at *t*=`a` and *t*=`b` respectively, you know that the result `w` will start at *t*=`a+b`. Since you also know the length of `w` and the time between samples `Ts`, you can define the time axis for `w` as `a+b + (0:length(w)-1)*Ts`.

In your case, since

```
t = -5:0.1:5;
```

you are defining `x` and `y` with time origin `t(1)` = `5` and sample spacing `t(2)-t(2)`= `0.1`. So you need to create the time axis for `w` as follows (replace your second to last line):

```
t_2 = 2*t(1) + (0:length(w)-1)*(t(2)-t(1));
```

With this, you will see that the two deltas of `x`, located at *t*=`-1` and *t*=`1`, appear at *t*=`2` and *t*=`4` respectively when you run `stem(t_2,w)`.